Is the research of extensions of Catalan's Conjecture still active today?
I am an outlier of number theory. Since one of my friend is working on Arakelov geometry and algebraic geometry, I sometimes also read materials on contemporary number theory.
Mathematicians are more concerned with ABC conjecture. If it holds, the extensions of Catalan's conj are down to earth. Nevertheless, the extensions of CC could provide strong evidence to the correctness of ABC conj.
So I am curious, is the research of extensions of Catalan's Conjecture still active today? Any mathematicians working on it? Any recent progress?

By "extensions of Catalan's conjecture" do you mean Pillai's conjecture?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198113/can-we-prove-that-there-are-no-two-perfect-powers-with-difference-6 summarizes the situation as of the year 2017. Michael Bennett continues to work on related problems, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.05553 and his paper in Transactiions of the AMS, https://www.ams.org/tran/2023-376-01/S0002-9947-2022-08734-1/S0002-9947-2022-08734-1.pdf

Yes, including Pillai's. I ask this question in a broad sense. Also, there are Beal's conj, and that...I do not know its English name: x^a+y^b=c^z has no nontrivial solutions of natural numbers.@TimothyChow

Thx@GerryMyerson

Isn't that just the Beal problem?

It has been clear that one guy made a joke,haha. Sorry...@GerryMyerson
